# TensorFlow Supervisor just stores the latest five models

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using TensorFlow's Supervisor to train my own model. I followed the official guide to set `save_model_secs` to be 600. However, I strangely find the path `log_dir` merely saves the latest five models and automatically discard models generated earlier. I carefully read the source code `supervisor.py` but cannot find the relevant removal code or mechanism why just five models can be saved all along the training process. Does any have any hint to help me? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.train.Supervisor` has a `saver` argument. If not given, it will use a default. This is configured to only store the last five checkpoints. You can overwrite this by passing your own `tf.train.Saver` object.

[See here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) for the docs. There are essentially two ways of storing more checkpoints when creating the `Saver`:

1. Pass some large integer to the `max_to_keep` argument. If you have enough storage, passing 0 or `None` should result in *all* checkpoints being kept.
2. `Saver` also has an argument `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours`. This will give you a separate "stream" of checkpoints that will be kept indefinitely. So for example you could store checkponts every 600 seconds (via the `save_model_secs` argument to `Supervisor`), but only keep the five most recent of those, but *additionally* save checkpoints each, say, 30 minutes (0.5 hours) all of which will be kept.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It is just the place where the "bug" lies.